# Using jQuery Table of Contents - contents too long for page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using the TOC plugin from here [TOC Code](http://projects.jga.me/toc/index.html), I have everything running along just fine, contents to the left, laid out almost as I wanted. I just realized there is no way too scroll or maybe a collapsing tree the contents that have exceeded the page height.

My CSS is not great, so some added help here would be greatly appreciated. The code I'm using is here:

```
$('#toc').toc({
    'selectors': 'h1,h2,h3', //elements to use as headings
    'container': 'body', //element to find all selectors in
    'smoothScrolling': true, //enable or disable smooth scrolling on click
    'prefix': 'toc', //prefix for anchor tags and class names
    'onHighlight': function(el) {}, //called when a new section is highlighted 
    'highlightOnScroll': true, //add class to heading that is currently in focus
    'highlightOffset': 100, //offset to trigger the next headline
    'anchorName': function(i, heading, prefix) { //custom function for anchor name
        return prefix + i;
    },
    'headerText': function(i, heading, $heading) { //custom function building the header-item text
        return $heading.text();
    },
    'itemClass': function(i, heading, $heading, prefix) { // custom function for item class
        return $heading[0].tagName.toLowerCase();
    }
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 20px 0 180px
}

a {
    color: #369
}

body {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: black;
    color: white
}

article {
    max-width: 944px;
    margin: auto
}

h1 {
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 48px
}

h2 {
    font-size: 42px;
    line-height: 48px;
    margin-top: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 24px
}

h3 {
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 48px;
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 0
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
#toc a {
    font-family: 'Voces', sans-serif
}

p,
ul {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 24px
}

small,
aside {
    font-size: 10px
}

code {
    word-wrap: break-word
}

.repo-stats iframe {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px
}

#toc {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #333;
    box-shadow: inset -5px 0 5px 0 #000;
    width: 170px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: #fff
}

#toc ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none
}

#toc li {
    padding: 5px 10px
}

#toc a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block
}

#toc .toc-h2 {
    padding-left: 10px
}

#toc .toc-h3 {
    padding-left: 30px
}

#toc .toc-active {
    background: #369;
    box-shadow: inset -5px 0 10px -5px #000
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: 1) Thanks Rory

2) Is there a realistic way to allow the left panel to scroll or maybe tree-collapse to make is usable?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed "overflow-y: scroll"